# (ValueError: Columns must be same length as key) from sentiment analysis

Tags: python, split, sentiment-analysis

I have been executing a sentiment analysis, and have returned the positive and negative outcomes to my pd.DataFrame in the following manner.

| author | Text | Sentiment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12323 | this is text | (0.25, 0.35) |

However, when I want to split the sentiment column (which consists of Polarity and Subjectivity), I get the following error:

`ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

I have tried multiple approaches:

- str.split
- str.extract
- rounding

With the rounding approach I get an error mentioning the float NaN's could not be multiplied. So I suppose that there is a NaN in there somewhere. However, when I look for NaN's I get this answer:

```
author_id       0
text_stemmed    0
sentiment       0
dtype: int64
```

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: changed case from `df['sentiment']` to `df['Sentiment']`

The `string` methods won't work because it's not a string but a `set` stored in the cell.

You can do this to create a new column:

```
df['sentiment_0'] = df['Sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['sentiment_1'] = df['Sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

or

```
df['sentiment_0'], df['sentiment_1'] = df['Sentiment'].explode()
```

Comment: Thanks Rutger! When I execute both of the suggested solutions I receive a KeyError: 'sentiment'. Which doesn't make sense to me since the column is called sentiment.

Comment: It's case sensitive. Yours is Sentiment probably. You can check with: print(df.columns)

Comment: Ah yes perfect. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Don't forget to set the question to resolved if it is :)

Comment: "set stored in the cell." Tuple rather than set, no?

Comment: Oops! You got me there. Doubted it while typing.